# load data from hive to Spanner google db

Tags: hive, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

How to load data from hive to Spanner db? Bulk load is available in spanner but couldn't find any documents for this.

I find this link but not having required information https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/bulk-loading

Answer (score 0):

We'll be coming out with a Dataflow (Apache Beam) connector which will help you import into Cloud Spanner. We're exploring Avro as an import file type.

Comment: Thanks Albert1 Is there a way to write python/Java code (code in hadoop) to insert data from hadoop to cloud spanner?

Answer (score 0):

There are now multiple possible import options for Cloud Spanner. The options are listed here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/import-export-overview

This page explains how to use the Dataflow (Apache Beam) connector with Cloud Spanner: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/import-non-spanner